# Plotting order statistics in R

Tags: r, plot, piecewise

I need to plot the joint density function of a bivariate random vector of order statistics which is defined by:

```
f(x,y) = (n!)*f(x)*f(y) for x < y and 0 otherwise
```

where **f** is the density function of a univariate random variable. For example, `f(x)=e^(-x)`.

I do not know if I must use `persp` and how to fix the support with the condition `x<y`.

Thank you very much.
Julio

Comment: It would be much easier if you included a specific example. is that   an n-factorial in the equation? Where is `n` coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical workflow for this sort of plotting is to define an x and y grid, create your function (in your case you would use `ifelse` to check your `x < y` condition), apply the function over the grid with `outer`, and finally plot with `persp`.

```
f <- function(x) exp(-x)
g <- function(x, y) ifelse(x < y, f(x)*f(y), 0)
x <- seq(0, 1, length.out=50)
y <- seq(0, 1, length.out=50)
z <- outer(x, y, g)
persp(x, y, z, theta = 30, phi = 30, expand = 0.5, col = "lightblue")
```

[image]

In your example, n! appears to just be a scalar, so it wouldn't affect the shape of the plot.